# Error: Cannot resolve module 'module' in path/.../rewire/lib

Tags: reactjs, flux

I am using `rewire` prior to `require` method in my React/Flux app, to load components. But after installation I got this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/rewire/lib/rewire.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'module' in /Users/path/node_modules/rewire/lib
 @ ./~/rewire/lib/rewire.js 1:13-30

ERROR in ./~/rewire/lib/rewire.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/path/node_modules/rewire/lib
 @ ./~/rewire/lib/rewire.js 2:9-22

ERROR in ./~/rewire/lib/moduleEnv.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'module' in /Users/path/node_modules/rewire/lib
 @ ./~/rewire/lib/moduleEnv.js 3:13-30

ERROR in ./~/rewire/lib/moduleEnv.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/path/node_modules/rewire/lib
 @ ./~/rewire/lib/moduleEnv.js 4:9-22
```

While googling I found similar issue, but no desirable solution. Does anyone know what is the issue or conflict about and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a webpack issue.

Since you're trying to use rewire, I'll assume you plan to run your tests through NodeJS and not a browser. Otherwise, check out [rewire-webpack](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire-webpack).

Rewire expects a NodeJS environment, but by default webpack targets a browser environment, and as such doesn't know about the standard NodeJS modules that rewire might depend on.

You need to set the [`target`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target) property of your webpack config to `"node"` in order to let webpack know it should consider standard NodeJS modules as externals.

Comment: Thanks @Morhaus, you are right. instead of setting `target` I used the `rewire-webpack` and it works great